# Heroku socket.io server runs locally, but not anywhere else

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, websocket, socket.io

Basically my socket.io server is only working for.. one computer only, I suppose. It works if I use Chrome, Chrome incognito, Edge. I tried using the app with my phone, while on the same Wifi, and that's where I encountered problems. It looked like socket.io just wouldn't work then. I feel like it's only working for one client (maybe ip, port issues?)

I use socket.io in pair with React js, and oh boy it was pain in the arse to make them work both locally and on Heroku.

Here's my server file /src/server/index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const axios = require("axios");
const port = process.env.PORT || 4001; // Only this port works for some reason
const index = require("./routes/index");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server); // < Interesting!

io = socketIo.listen(app);

io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10);  // Recommended from online guys
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../index')));
app.get('/', (req, res, next) =>
  res.sendFile(index))

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("New client connected");
})

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

I use config file to dynamically change the server and I import it every time I need to connect to my socket via socket.io-client

```
let server = 'ws://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket';

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

if (env === 'development') {
    server = 'http://127.0.0.1:4001';
}

module.exports = server;
```

What could be the problem? Why is only working on my root computer? Could be a dyno problem or something else?
I'm a complete beginner with both heroku and socket.io, so any information would be helpful.

**EDIT:

I am not sure, but I feel like a server running in my VS Code made it work in my heroku app. I have turned it off and the server just keeps sending net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

Comment: I have a same problem too, Socket.IO works on localhost but fails on Heroku.

Comment: @TríPhan I got it all working. Check this out.
`Choosing the right buildpack can help, and neither heroku/heroku-buildpack-static nor mars/create-react-app-buildpack is the right choice if you've got back-end code: "If your goal is to make a single app that combines React UI with a server-side backend (Node, Ruby, Python…), then this buildpack is not the answer." But the mars one recommends mars/heroku-cra-node if you have a Node.js back-end.` – Chris

Comment: @TríPhan As said in my newer thread `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131883/how-do-i-rewrite-all-urls-to-index-html-in-heroku`

Comment: Ah, I just solved my problem, the `dotenv` module made my app go wrong on Heroku and I removed it

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Using `mars/heroku-cra-node` buildpack is a must. It seperates react-ui and server code. Port config: `const port = process.env.PORT || 4001`,
Client listens for: `let server = window.location.hostname`
Also good to have a seperate config file for clientside that has the following:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
if (env === 'development') {
    server = 'http://localhost:4001';
}
module.exports = server;
```

Then you won't have to change ports and servers in development (VSCode) or production (Heroku).