# How do I rewrite all urls to index.html in Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-router

My Heroku app is using React with React Router. I use Switch to navigate through different components, so the URL changes as well (e.g. `/room/4141`). However, if I reload the page, it doesn't act like if it was a React app, but instead it searches for the mentioned `.html` file.

I used this Buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git but it seems to do nothing in regards with pages being rewritten to `index.html`.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour and rewrite all URLs to `index.html`?

**EDIT:
I'm not familiar enough with express, but here's how the `index.html` is served.

```
const express = require("../../node_modules/express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = module.exports.io = require('../../node_modules/socket.io/lib')(server)
const path = require("path")

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../build')));
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../build')));
    console.log("DEBUG HERE", __dirname, path.join(__dirname+'../../build'));
    //
    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'../../build/index.html'));
    })
  }
  //build mode
  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'../../public/index.html'));
  })
```

Comment: Can you use client-side routing with hashes, e.g. `https://yoursite.com/#room/4141`? That should work out of the box.

Comment: Seems like using hashes also doesn't make a difference. My page is just not loaded at all. Or am I doing it wrong? `<Route path="/#room/:roomCode" component={Lobby} />` *EDIT: reloading the page also returns `Not Found`

Answer (score 3):

That buildpack [can be configured](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static/blob/master/README.md#configuration) via  a JSON file:

> You can configure different options for your static application by writing a `static.json` in the root folder of your application.

One of the [sample routing configurations](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static/blob/master/README.md#user-content-custom-routes) looks like it does exactly what you want:

> When serving a single page app, it's useful to support wildcard URLs that serves the index.html file, while also continuing to serve JS and CSS files correctly. Route ordering allows you to do both:
>
> ```
> {
>   "routes": {
>     "/assets/*": "/assets/",
>     "/**": "index.html"
>   }
> }
> ```